# android Google Map not working on activity onresume

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, onresume

I am using google map v2 and its working fine in my project.
I made three different classes to show the map in three different cases.
1. But now i changed these three into single activity.
2. On Condition base i am starting the same activity again and again.
3. On loading first time its working fine
4. closing the second or third activity its closes the activity and comes back but it is not loading the map now to show the previous activity map markers.

It says few warning and error as well

```
getEntry failing because entryIndex 906 is beyond type entryCount 31
Failure getting entry for 0x7f0b038a (t=10 e=906) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
```

Error is

```
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

Comment: destroy view when switch to another view

Comment: i need to show the previous screens as well...